# workflow_run only on push

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following workflow:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop]
  pull_request:

jobs:
   ....
```

```
name: deploy

on:
  release:
    types: [released]
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["ci"]
    branches: [develop]
    types: [completed]
```

The problem I have is that when I create a PR from the `develop` to the `main` branch it also runs the `deploy` workflow. Is there any way to prevent this? and just run the `deploy` workflow on push after the CI finishes?

Thanks